# Linux for programming? Which one?

Tags: linux, open-source, software-development

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask but I honestly would love an answer. I am a Software Engineering student and I have the following dilemma. Till now I have used Windows, I like Windows it is simple and well known but I realized something the last weeks. Windows consumes a LOT of memory. Its ok when i want to play games or when i want to do conventional stuff but regarding school work and programming should I switch to Linux? Is it more lightweight in terms of non-gaming, non-photo editing, non-video editing etc. processes? And shall I go with Fedora or Ubuntu? Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: Questions of opinion aren't well suited for a Stack Exchange site (which [softewarerecs.se] is), rather we stick to an objective question/answer format. That said, Linux is a very different world than Windows. There are a lot of advantages, but it takes time to get used to new and different systems. You'll really have to make that decision yourself. That said, it's not hard to set up a dual boot with both Linux and Windows so you can switch between them at will. I would recommend ubuntu over Fedora since it is more beginner friendly.

Comment: Which software do you want to keep for Linux and are you sure that there is particular software for Linux? Sure, Linux has a lot of open source alternatives but they probably don't have nearly as many features as Windows software. Also, are you sure that it's not _your_ script that consumes a good portion of your RAM?

Comment: From what I have seen when I turn on windows it consumes by default around 3gigs of memory at least! Not only on my machine but most of the student's have problems with their memory especially when they want to run docker. While i love windows in terms of gaming performance I really want something more lightweight on my day to day operations.

Comment: OS recommendations are on-topic, but you would need much more precise requirements. There are hundreds of OSes that allow you to do programming and don't consume much memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you start programming on the Ubuntu platform you'll probably use it again and again, because Ubuntu is a versatile OS and many programming language compilers and other programming packages can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Compared with Fedora Ubuntu has much more programming packages in its default repositories which translates to much less packages that need to be manually downloaded or installed from third-party sources.

Ubuntu is better supported than Fedora, and the larger number of packages in the default Ubuntu repositories makes a big difference to a programmer. Ubuntu is open source, so you can customize it, and give it whatever interface you want. I like the default Ubuntu interface because it is good for my workflow.

Ubuntu is a bit more lightweight than Windows 10 and it can be customized to be even more lightweight by installing a more lightweight desktop environment, although the default desktop environment is more programmer friendly. If your computer has a lot of memory Ubuntu will make use of it, which I regard as a positive feature because Ubuntu runs faster than Windows on every computer that I have ever tested. LibreOffice (Ubuntu's default office suite) runs much faster than Microsoft Office on every computer that I have ever tested.

Comment: I was leaning toward Ubuntu as it is the one that we are using for our test exams but i fell in love with the fedora interface.

Comment: Ubuntu is better supported than Fedora, and the larger number of packages in the default Ubuntu repositories makes a big difference to a programmer. Ubuntu is open source, so you can customize it, and give it whatever interface you want. I like the default Ubuntu interface because it is good for my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want consistency, use a Linux that resembles those installed on your university's computer pools, because sooner or later you'll interact with them to submit assignments, run cloud-/cluster-based programs, etc.

Check out which Linux Systems their campus licenses cover for popular third-party software that is important to you.  Have they licensed their backup software, or their antivirus license, that they give to students, for Debian or for Suse, Redhat based Systems, etc.?

If you are into graphics programming, check which platform best supports your GPU driver inside your laptop or PC (NVidia/AMD/Intel...). Things change quickly in this regard, GPU/platform driver support on linux.

Comment: you could upvote or finally accept he question then